# Get list of all installed apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, jailbreak

I would like to get a list of all installed apps(NSArray). My app is a jailbreak app and is located in/Applications so Sandbox is no problem there. Is there any way to get a list of app store apps? I've already seen this in other apps (Activator, SBSettings...). I have no idea how to do this, because all of the apps sandboxes have that huge code, so i don't know how it would be possible to access the .app folder inside the sandbox.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this code snippet:

```
 #import "InstalledAppReader.h"

static NSString* const installedAppListPath = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist";

@interface InstalledAppReader()

-(NSArray *)installedApp;
-(NSMutableDictionary *)appDescriptionFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

@end


@implementation InstalledAppReader

#pragma mark - Init
-(NSMutableArray *)desktopAppsFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSMutableArray *desktopApps = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *appKey in dictionary)
    {
        [desktopApps addObject:appKey];
    }
    return desktopApps;
}

-(NSArray *)installedApp
{    
    BOOL isDir = NO;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: installedAppListPath isDirectory: &isDir] && !isDir) 
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *cacheDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: installedAppListPath];
        NSDictionary *system = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"System"];
        NSMutableArray *installedApp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self desktopAppsFromDictionary:system]];

        NSDictionary *user = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"User"]; 
        [installedApp addObjectsFromArray:[self desktopAppsFromDictionary:user]];

        return installedApp;
    }

    DLOG(@"can not find installed app plist");
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Is this unsing a private API?

Comment: This is not a private API, but we get access to private folder. Apple will reject your app. Use this code only  for jailbroken iPhone.

Comment: @Fedorchuk,  how can i get this installed application list from normal iOS devices i mean without jailbroken iPhones, plz help me to do this.

Comment: without jailbroken iPhones you can not do this.

Comment: why does it always returns "can not find installed app plist"

Comment: @Funny: You were probably trying on iOS 8. This only works on previous versions, as that plist doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: any other method for greater than iOS 8 version

Answer (score 7):

On jailbroken iPhones, you can just read the `/Applications` folder. All installed applications go there. Just list the directories in `/Applications` using `NSFileManager`:

```
NSArray *appFolderContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:@"/Applications"];
```

Comment: That reads only the pre installed apps and the cydia apps, im talking about the app store apps.

Comment: Try the `mobile` user's applications folder then: `/private/var/mobile/Applications`

Comment: The original answer doesn't work in iOS 8 (that plist is missing) so this answer is the best so far.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I have found a framework called [iHasApp](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp). Here is a good solution to return a dictionary with app name, identifier and icon: [Finding out what Apps are installed](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/37103-finding-out-what-apps-installed.html)

Answer (score 2):

There's also the `AppList library`, which will do all of the dirty work for you: 
[rpetrich/AppList](https://github.com/rpetrich/AppList)
It's used in a lot of Jailbreak tweaks, so I don't know why it wasn't suggested here before.

One way to get just AppStore apps would be to check the value of `isSystemApplication` for each app returned in the list. Those with the value set to `NO` are regular AppStore apps. There's also a function **`applicationsFilteredUsingPredicate:predicate`**, so perhaps it would even be possible to filter the list beforehand.