# iOS – Check what applications have Facebook access

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

Is there a way to check what apps have access to Facebook in iOS6? For instance if **Calendar.app** has access, or if **Contacts.app** has access?

I'm developing an app that access inbuilt Calendar.app to extract events (through EventKit).

I also encourage the user to connect with Facebook so we can retrieve the user's Facebook events.

This works perfectly, only one issue is when user has allowed the Calendar.app to access Facebook then I will have both extracted the Facebook events through EventKit and also through the Facebook iOS SDK so I will have duplicated data...

If the user has not allowed Calendar.app to access Facebook then there will of course be no issues.

Comment: I think u can't it is private API for apple if u use it your app. will reject

Comment: here the only thing u can do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226406/get-list-of-all-installed-apps

Comment: i think there is a way to do it with only Facebook privacy , i don't try it before but i think u can get list of app that Facebook Account allow to access it. but still u need to know if the user Turn it ON or OFF :(