# Listing all installed apps on iPhone Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I need to list all installed apps on iPhone with the help of coding. I am using a jailbroken iPhone. I have used ihasapp API, but it is not showing me the complete list of all installed apps. Please help me with the code.

Comment: Check this: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22289-possible-retrieve-these-information.html

Comment: I have already gone through it. But for this we need to pass the bundle id to check whether a particular app is installed or not. But I need to list all installed apps.

Comment: Ok i am also googling & find this link...but if you succeeded then also please tell me the way that you follow....Best of luck.

Comment: sure vishal I will post my solution as answer if I am able to implement it successfully

Comment: OK good Best of luck I am waiting your answer bro....I know you can do it....

Comment: Thanx vishal fro encouraging me, I have been really struggling over this task for past few weeks. Hope I could find a solution for this at the earliest.

Comment: Of course, You will surely find solution for this...My wishes is with you....Every great work are not solve without difficulties....Just try & try hard in the end you will surely win....

Comment: Type this string (`[jailbreak] list installed apps`) into the stack overflow search field, and you'll get some answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of all installed apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226406/get-list-of-all-installed-apps)

Comment: ion iOS8 the com.apple.mobile.installation.plist is deleted with what it's replaced please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the AppList library myself to get a list of all installed apps. It uses private frameworks so it's also jailbreak-only. Check it out at https://github.com/rpetrich/AppList.

Update: @Nate is correct about this already being asked and answered. Check out: [Get list of all installed apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7226406/381233)

Comment: Did you compile it yourself or download it via Cydia?

Comment: Have you tried using the Cydia version? That worked for me on iOS 5 and 6.

Comment: I have downloaded the Cydia Version but it has just downloaded Deb Archive file and now I don't know how to execute it in xcode

Comment: The way I do it is to link to the dylib with Xcode. But that's a bit too much for a comment, if you'd like to ask about this, I (or someone who's faster), will be happy to answer. As far as I can see, this hasn't been asked before.

Comment: Can you please explain how to link dylib file with xcode my dear friend

Comment: Do you want to ask separately, in a new question? This will make it easier to answer ;)

Comment: cann't you tell me here itself, I will be thankful to you man

Comment: Not enough space in the comments, better to ask a separate question. If people like your question, you get more points!

Comment: Please share some idea here itself. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I got a list of all installed application in my iPhone. It uses private framework but it's not jail broken device. Lookout below piece of code.

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>

    Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
    SEL selector=NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace");
    NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:selector];

    SEL selectorALL = NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications");
    NSLog(@"apps: %@", [workspace performSelector:selectorALL]);
```

I have tried this code and it's workings well on iOS9.

Comment: Great!!. Can you help me how to parse bundle identifier and application name??

Comment: This code will print the name of the first object  
`NSObject* oPoop = [sApplications objectAtIndex:0];  
SEL selectorName = NSSelectorFromString(@"itemName");  
NSLog(@"%@", [oPoop performSelector:selectorName]);`

Answer (score 4):

There is a private API SBSCopyApplicationDisplayIdentifiers

It's signature is following

CFArrayRef SBSCopyApplicationDisplayIdentifiers(bool onlyActive, bool debuggable);

If you link to SpringboardServices framework and use it, it will return the list of installed apps.

**Update 1**

Here is example of usage copied from [here](https://github.com/comex/sbsutils/blob/master/sbbundleids.c)

```
CFArrayRef SBSCopyApplicationDisplayIdentifiers(bool onlyActive, bool debuggable);

int main() {
    char buf[1024];
    CFArrayRef ary = SBSCopyApplicationDisplayIdentifiers(false, false);
    for(CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(ary); i++) {
        CFStringGetCString(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(ary, i),buf, sizeof(buf), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to link to pravite framework SpringboardServices.

Comment: Hi Victor, can you please submit a piece of code so that I can run and see the results

Comment: Hi victor, the code snippet you send is in c language but I need in objective c language dear

Comment: @KaushikAjmera: In iOS development, you can mix C code with Objective C. Actually most of older frameworks (like CoreFoundation) are C frameworks.

Comment: How to link SpringboardServices when it's not available?

Comment: Generally. There are two ways. One is dynamic loading - use dlopen and dlsym. And you can link to it statically. However, it's a little bit cumbersome - usually I add some public framerowk and after manually edit xcode configuration file to point to SoringboardServices

Comment: Is it working for iOS 8?, i have tried but not working, is there any problem with my code,or is it not working with iOS 8?

Comment: I am not sure. It worked well on iOS 6 and 7. However, Apple did a lot of hardening around private api's in iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot to get the installed app list on iOS 11. But there is code to check the application currently installed on this device.

```
//If the device is iOS11
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 11.0) {
    NSBundle *container = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileContainerManager.framework"];
    if ([container load]) {
        Class appContainer = NSClassFromString(@"MCMAppContainer");

        id test = [appContainer performSelector:@selector(containerWithIdentifier:error:) withObject:bundleId withObject:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",test);
        if (test) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return NO;

}
```

Comment: What will `the bundleId` mentioned in above code. I used the bundleId obtained from `container` NSBundle. But the variable `test` returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSArray *appList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Applications" error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",appList);
```

Comment: This doesn't list apps that are installed via the App Store.

Comment: This list apps that are installed in iOS by default.