# Get a list of installed apps in an App Store approved application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've come across [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iconical-customize-your-iphone/id662522133?mt=8), which as one of the functionalities, can scan your phone to retrieve a list of installed apps. I have read the thread [on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226406/get-list-of-all-installed-apps) concerning retrieving a list of installed apps by accessing private folders, private APIs, etc. but the answers only apply to jailbroken/sandbox-free applications, which can't be put on the App Store. But this app has been approved and is available now on the store.

How is it that they are retrieving a list of the users installed applications without the use of private APIs?

Answer (score -1):

After further analysis, I've discovered that they aren't retrieving a list of *every* installed application per se, rather they are most likely looping over a database of known popular app URLs (in the app's case, 17,000 urls, probably retrieved from a server somewhere), by calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]` repeatedly for each URL and adding it to an array when it returns `YES`.