# Getting the name of an app from a Bundle ID other than my own on iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use this code:

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:item] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
```

To get the name of an app from its Bundle Identifier, however for all non-stock apps this method is returning nil. I have tried to look for ways to solve this to no avail. How can I get the name of an app from the bundle ID in iOS 8?

EDIT: To clarify, I want to use this for apps other than my own - I asked a question earlier on the same topic but all of the answers were for my app only, so I have explained the question further.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to get the bundle of another arbitrary app?

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the bundle of another app. You have only access to your app's bundle. When you use `bundleWithIdentifier:` the iOS looks for a bundle that matches the provided identifier within your app's sandbox. In your above mentioned case, there will be no such `NSBundle` available, so it'll return nil.

According to [NSBundle Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleWithIdentifier:)

> `bundleWithIdentifier:`
>
> Returns the previously created NSBundle instance that has the
>   specified bundle identifier.
>
> #### Declaration
>
> **Swift**
>
> `init?(identifier identifier: String) -> NSBundle`
>
> **Objective-C**
>
> `+ (NSBundle *)bundleWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `identifier`
>
> The identifier for an existing NSBundle instance.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The previously created NSBundle instance that has the bundle
>   identifier identifier. Returns nil if the requested bundle is not
>   found.
>
> #### Discussion
>
> **This method is typically used by frameworks and plug-ins to locate
>   their own bundle at runtime.** This method may be somewhat more
>   efficient than trying to locate the bundle using the `bundleForClass:`
>   method. However, if the initial lookup of an already loaded and cached
>   bundle with the specified identifier fails, this method uses
>   potentially time-consuming heuristics to attempt to locate the bundle.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would go about accessing another app's bundle?

Comment: @JamesWilliams: AFAIK in non-jailbroken devices you can't do that.

Comment: I am on a jailbroken device.

Comment: @JamesWilliams: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226406/get-list-of-all-installed-apps